# How can I keep multiple NSManagedContext's in sync?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-data

I've spent a couple of hours tonight trying to create a setup whereby I have three managed object contexts - one attached to my application's delegate, one in an `NSObject` subclass responsible for `UITableView` updates (via an `NSFetchedResultsController`) and one in an `NSOperation` subclass.

I can get the changes from the `NSOperation` subclass to the app delegate to flow through just fine by observing `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`, and firing off `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:` on my main thread, but when I try to do the same thing from my `UITableView` data source, I get the following exception:

```
2010-02-19 02:00:39.750 MyApp[44687:207] Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing: *** -[NSCFArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object at objects[0] with userInfo (null)
2010-02-19 02:00:39.750 MyApp[44687:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSCFArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object at objects[0]'
```

I'd appreciate any advice - all of my previous designs involving Core Data managed object contexts have been very simple 1:1 sync scenarios. Is what I'm proposing even possible?

Comment: Have you used the debugger? What does it tell you about your attempt to insert nil into an NSArray? Specifically, break on objc_exception_throw and pinpoint part of your code that's causing this problem.

Comment: Joshua, it's actually coming from:

    - (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
     NSArray    *paths   = [NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath];

Apparently NSArray can't be initialised by an indexPath of {0,0}. Still working out why this is happening.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A better question is WHY are you trying to keep multiple contexts in sync.  Having two, one for your main application usage and one for imports makes sense but the imports context does not need to be kept in sync and you already know how to feed your main context off the import context.

So what is that third context for?  IF it is just for table view updates, that is a bad design and you should be using a single context for the entire UI layer.  That is most likely the correct solution to your problem instead of trying to keep three contexts juggling in the air.

Comment: That's the answer I needed to hear. For some reason I'd convinced myself (at 2am) that I needed another managed object context. I was just being greedy!

Thanks as always, Marcus!